Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\mu\lvert u-s \rvert-\lambda s}ds$
Find
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\mu\lvert u-s \rvert-\lambda s}ds$$
Here's my work:
I've got
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\mu\lvert u-s \rvert-\lambda s}ds+\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-\mu\lvert u-s \rvert-\lambda s}ds &=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\mu(u-s)-\lambda s}ds+\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-\mu(s-u)-\lambda s}ds \tag1 \\[4pt]
&=e^{-\mu u}\int_{0}^{t}e^{(\mu-\lambda)s}ds+e^{-\mu u}\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-(\mu+\lambda)s}ds \tag2 \\[4pt]
&=e^{-\mu u}\left[(\mu-\lambda)e^{(\mu-\lambda)s}\right]_{0}^{t} \\[4pt]
&\quad +e^{-\mu u}\left[-(\mu+\lambda)e^{-(\mu+\lambda)s}\right]_{t}^{\infty} \tag3
\end{align}$$
So $$\begin{align}
&e^{-\mu u}[(\mu-\lambda)e^{(\mu-\lambda)t}-(\mu-\lambda)]+e^{-\mu u}[0+(\mu+\lambda)e^{-(\mu+\lambda)t}] \tag4\\[4pt]
= \quad &e^{-\mu u}[(\mu-\lambda)(e^{(\mu-\lambda)t}-1)]+e^{\mu u}[(\mu+\lambda)e^{-(\mu+\lambda)t}] \tag5
\end{align}$$
From the work shown above, is everything correct up to here? If so, then how should I proceed and simplify from here in order to get the correct answer? I know that I should factor out some common terms but what should I factor out?
Okay, so here's my revised work below:
$\int_{0}^{u}e^{-\mu\lvert u-s \rvert-\lambda s}ds+\int_{u}^{\infty}e^{-\mu\lvert u-s \rvert-\lambda s}ds=\int_{0}^{u}e^{-\mu(u-s)-\lambda s}ds+\int_{u}^{\infty}e^{-\mu(s-u)-\lambda s}ds=e^{-\mu u}\int_{0}^{u}e^{(\mu-\lambda)s}ds+e^{\mu u}\int_{u}^{\infty}e^{-(\mu+\lambda)s}ds=e^{-\mu u}[(\mu-\lambda)e^{(\mu-\lambda)s}]_{0}^{u}+e^{\mu u}[-(\mu+\lambda)e^{-(\mu+\lambda)s}]_{u}^{\infty}=e^{\mu u}[(\mu-\lambda)e^{(\mu-\lambda)u}-(\mu-\lambda)]+e^{\mu u}[0+(\mu+\lambda)e^{-(\mu+\lambda)u}]=e^{-\mu u}[(\mu-\lambda)(e^{(\mu-\lambda)u}-1)]+e^{\mu u}[(\mu+\lambda)e^{-(\mu+\lambda)u}]=(\mu-\lambda)(e^{-\lambda u}-e^{-\mu u})+(\mu+\lambda)e^{-\lambda u}.$
From the work shown above, what should I do in order to simplify the whole thing? How can $(\mu-\lambda)$ and $(\mu+\lambda)$ be on the denominator?

When you integrate $\int e^{ks}ds = \frac1ke^{ks}+c$, that is how you get the factors on the denominator, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty e^{-\mu|u-s|-\lambda s}ds 
&= e^{-\mu u}\int_0^u e^{(\mu -\lambda) s}ds + e^{\mu u}\int_u^\infty e^{-(\mu +\lambda) s}ds \\
&= e^{-\mu u}\frac1{\mu -\lambda}[ e^{(\mu -\lambda) s}]_0^u - e^{\mu u}\frac1{\mu +\lambda} [e^{-(\mu +\lambda) s}]_u^\infty \\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda u} - e^{-\mu u}}{\mu -\lambda} + \frac{e^{-\lambda u}}{\mu +\lambda}  \\
\end{align*}
Edit: you can then group as you wish, e.g.:
$$\frac{2\mu e^{-\lambda u}}{\mu^2-\lambda^2} - \frac{e^{-\mu u}}{\mu -\lambda} $$

I see where I got it wrong now. I've totally forgot about that integration rule of $\int e^{ks}ds=\frac{1}{k}e^{ks}+C$. No wonder it didn't make sense at all. Thank you so much for your help!
